# How to add the sum of some column at the end of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a pandas dataframe with 11 columns. I want to add the sum of all values of columns 9 and column 10 to the end of table. So far I tried 2 methods:

- Assigning the data to the cell with `dataframe.iloc[rownumber, 8]`. This results in an out of bound error.
- Creating a vector with some blank: '  ' by using the following code:

```py
total = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', dataframe['Column 9'].sum(), dataframe['Column 10'].sum(), '']
dataframe = dataframe.append(total)
```

The result was not nice as it added the total vector as a vertical vector at the end rather than a horizontal one. What can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need use [pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) **with `ignore_index=True`**

so use:

```
dataframe=dataframe.append(dataframe[['Column 9','Column 10']].sum(),ignore_index=True).fillna('')
```

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['col1']=[1,2,3,4]
df['col2']=[2,3,4,5]
df['col3']=[5,6,7,8]
df['col4']=[5,6,7,8]
```

Using Append:

```
df=df.append(df[['col2','col3']].sum(),ignore_index=True)
print(df)


   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
1   2.0   3.0   6.0   6.0
2   3.0   4.0   7.0   7.0
3   4.0   5.0   8.0   8.0
4   NaN  14.0  26.0   NaN
```

Whitout NaN values:

```
df=df.append(df[['col2','col3']].sum(),ignore_index=True).fillna('')
print(df)

  col1  col2  col3 col4
0    1   2.0   5.0    5
1    2   3.0   6.0    6
2    3   4.0   7.0    7
3    4   5.0   8.0    8
4       14.0  26.0
```

Comment: What does ignore_index do?

Comment: You can see it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html if you do not use `ignore_index = True` would try to use Column 9 and Column 10 as the index of `rows` throwing the following error: `TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name`

Answer (score 1):

Create new DataFrame with sums. This example DataFrame has columns 'a' and 'b'. df1 is the DataFrame what need to be summed up and df3 is one line DataFrame only with sums:

```
data = [[df1.a.sum(),df1.b.sum()]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])
```

Then append it to end:

```
df1.append(df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

IICU , this is what you need (change numbers 8 & 9 to suit your needs)

```
df['total']=df.iloc[ : ,[8,9]].sum(axis=1) #horizontal sum
df['total1']=df.iloc[ : ,[8,9]].sum().sum() #Vertical sum
df.loc['total2']=df.iloc[ : ,[8,9]].sum() # vertical sum in rows for only columns 8 & 9
```

Example

```
a=np.arange(0, 11, 1)
b=np.random.randint(10, size=(5,11))
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=a, data=b)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   0   5   1   3   4   8   6   6   8   1   0
1   9   9   8   9   9   2   3   8   9   3   6
2   5   7   9   0   8   7   8   8   7   1   8
3   0   7   2   8   8   3   3   0   4   8   2
4   9   9   2   5   2   2   5   0   3   4   1

**output**
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  total   total1
0   0.0     5.0     1.0     3.0     4.0     8.0     6.0     6.0     8.0     1.0     0.0     9.0     48.0
1   9.0     9.0     8.0     9.0     9.0     2.0     3.0     8.0     9.0     3.0     6.0     12.0    48.0
2   5.0     7.0     9.0     0.0     8.0     7.0     8.0     8.0     7.0     1.0     8.0     8.0     48.0
3   0.0     7.0     2.0     8.0     8.0     3.0     3.0     0.0     4.0     8.0     2.0     12.0    48.0
4   9.0     9.0     2.0     5.0     2.0     2.0     5.0     0.0     3.0     4.0     1.0     7.0     48.0
total2  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     31.0    17.0    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: He said: The result was not nice, it added the total vector but it added as a vertical vector at the end rather than horizontal one. What can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

simply try this:(replace `test` with your dataframe name)

row wise sum(which you have asked for):

```
test['Total'] = test[['col9','col10']].sum(axis=1)
print(test)
```

column wise sum:

```
test.loc['Total'] = test[['col9','col10']].sum()
test.fillna('',inplace=True)
print(test)
```